# Three items (Current value, trend and YTD) in single panel in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

We've setup a new Splunk dashboard and I'm looking to improve the trend graphs/panels.

We now have three panels each telling us something about a specific type of event. These panels are shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Three separate panels]

Top to bottom,

- the first shows the number of events in the current rolling period (of 30 days).
- The second shows a trend graph of the number of events every day over the past 3 months.
- The third and last shows the number of events in this year to the current data (YTD).

I'd like to clean this up and combine it into one panel. Ideally it would look something like:

[image: Data combined into panel]

I've been messing with CSS files, but that is not a sustainable solution. 
Also I've found the Splunk documentation on how to [Generate a single value](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.3.1/Viz/SingleValueGenerate). This give me part of what I'm looking for. But this lacks the Year to Data value and I need the trend line to be more prominent.

[image: From Splunk, single value with trend but without YTD]

Any suggestions to how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a custom visualization of a numeric value. I would suggest you start by looking into existing numeric value visualizations from Splunkbase, then customize the visualization code (html/css/js) to do what you need it to.

From a quick view I just had, there is [Number Display Viz](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/4537/) which also has source code available under the GPL on github: https://github.com/ChrisYounger/number_display_viz

To show all three datapoints on a single panel, you can either tweak the html to retrieve data from three different searches, or use sub-searches to provide all data as a single result.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting all three visualizations in a single panel.  You'll need to edit the dashboard's source to do that, but it's very simple.  Just remove the `</panel></row><row><panel>` tags between the visualizations.

A simpler option would be to move the three panels onto the same row so they're next to each other.